# Carrinho de compras sql, php e ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estou fazendo o carrinho de compras e gostaria de saber se devo salvar os produtos que o usuário esta comprando em uma tabela ou não, qual a lógica para sempre mostrar o produto certo para o usuário certo?

Sei que posso usar o id do usuário mais todos os carrinhos de todos os usuários ficariam armazenados na mesma tabela? E tem como colocar um tempo para o produto ser excluído do carrinho?

E a outra pergunta sou novo usando ajax, como atualizo os valores do carrinho automaticamente?

Answer (score 1):

Isso depende muito da sua política de negócios, principalmente no que se refere a excluir os dados periodicamente ou não. Há modelos de negócio que não excluem e há outros que excluem (muitas vezes uma escolha errada). Eu prefiro nunca excluir nada. Quando necessitar remover algo irrelevante, porém importante para uma futura pesquisa, mova esses dados para um outro banco ou outra tabela de arquivamento, histórico, etc.

Sobre como referenciar um usuário ao carrinho, pode fazer isso com ID do cliente que está logado, conforme já mencionou. Todavia, para usuários não logados, pode usar cookie com um ID que o relacione a aquela informação.

É recomendado que salve os dados do carrinho, mesmo aqueles dados de usuários não logados pois isso é muito útil para analisar o comportamento dos usuários, quem abandona o carrinho, em que ponto o carrinho foi abandonado, o quê os usuários normalmente inserem no carrinho, quantidade, valor, datas, etc. Tudo isso é muito importante e interessante para direcionar campanhas de marketing e a logística em si.

Outro fator é que torna mais amigável ao usuário quando tem o carrinho salvo. Muitas vezes pode acontecer de perder a conexão e o usuário querer voltar a loja posteriormente. Então não terá o trabalho de encher novamente o carrinho. Quando o usuário retorna e vê que o carrinho foi salvo, a probabilidade dele efetuar a compra é maior. Do contrário, ele sentirá que terá um trabalho a mais em refazer a compra, desanimando-o e até desistindo da compra.

Esses são os pontos principais e mais óbvios de por que salvar os dados do carrinho.

Claro que, com o tempo o volume de dados começará a pesar muito. Nesse ponto você e/ou os donos do negócio é quem decide o que fazer com dados antigos. Se vai excluir ou não, ou apenas mover para um arquivamento de histórico, isso é uma decisão particular. Como citei acima, eu prefiro não excluir nada. Mesmo que pareça ser lixo, algum dia no futuro poderá precisar desses dados, seja para a logística ou para analisar rastros de usuários maliciosos, por exemplo.